# .NET RichTextBox Text change from code not recording undo

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, richtextbox

I am using a `RichTextBox` control in a text editor. I also have an undo function.

When I change the text inside the `RichTextBox` and press undo (`RichTextBox.Undo();`) eveything is fine and it does what it is supposed to.
But when I change the text from code using `RichTextBox.Text = "somestring"` it doesn't record that for undoing.
**Is there any way to enable this, preferably without keeping track of any changes myself?**

Answer (score 0):

If you want to totally exclude the operation from the code, I think it is hard to achieve.   And in your sample codes, if we paste the string text onto the RichTextBox, then we do “Ctrl + Z” or undo the operation, what effect do you want?   All the text disappeared?   Because if without the code operation here, if we just paste some string text onto a normal RichTextBox, an undo operation will just clear the text by undo the pasting action.   If you want the same effect, I think you could just use the following codes, or supposed you want some other effect under such conditions, please make your concern more clearly, we will still try to help.

---

```
    private void richTextBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)

    {

        if (e.Control && (e.KeyCode == Keys.Z))

        {

            while (this.richTextBox1.CanUndo &&

                this.richTextBox1.UndoActionName.Equals("Unknown"))

            {

                this.richTextBox1.Undo();

            }

        }

        else if (e.Control && (e.KeyCode == Keys.V))

        {

            HighLightText();

            e.Handled = true;

        }

        else if (e.Shift && (e.KeyCode == Keys.Insert))

        {

            HighLightText();

            e.Handled = true;

        }  

    }



    private void HighLightText()

    {

        int iCount = 0;

        int iWordPos = 0;

        DataFormats.Format myFormat = DataFormats.GetFormat(DataFormats.Text);

        this.richTextBox1.Paste(myFormat);

        string[] strSplitText = this.richTextBox1.Text.Split(' ');

        foreach (string strWord in strSplitText)

        {

            if (iCount % 2 == 0)

            {

                this.richTextBox1.Select(iWordPos, strWord.Length);

                this.richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Blue;

            }

            else

            {

                this.richTextBox1.Select(iWordPos, strWord.Length);

                this.richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Black;

            }

            iWordPos += strWord.Length + 1;

            iCount++;

        }

        this.richTextBox1.Select(this.richTextBox1.Text.Length - 1, 0);

    }
```

---

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `SelectedText` property, the changes will be registered for undo.

So instead of:

```
RichTextBox.Text = "somestring"
```

use

```
    RichTextBox.SelectAll();
    RichTextBox.SelectedText = "something";
```